# If Van Hohenheim is a living Philosopher's Stone, what does that make Edward and Alphonse?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

In episode 62 of Brotherhood series, when Father's stone was nearly depleted, he started to search desperately for a new one. When he saw Edward Elric pinned down, his expression suddenly changed and he started walking towards him, as if he had found one.

If they are part human, part Philosopher's Stone, isn't it kinda ironic that what they had been looking for was inside them all along?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a few different things to address here.

First off, **Edward and Alphonse are fully human**. This is actually addressed when Alphonse first finds out about his dad's origins. Essentially, he contains a philosopher's stone within himself, but he is still biologically human.

[image: "My soul is fused with the philosopher's stone, but the actual core that holds me together is myself, a human being."]
<sup>*Click to enlarge.*</sup>

Second, remember that **all humans are philosopher's stones**. Edward (kind of) states this in episode 41, and says that his life energy is identical to that of a philosopher's stone, and he's right. All humans are simply philosopher's stones containing exactly one soul.

[image: "Right now, I'm nothing more than a philosopher's stone made out of one soul!"]

Third, it is because of the above points that Father approached Edward. It wasn't because he'd get a lot of energy, like from a true, isolated stone (such as one of Kimblee's), but rather **because Edward had one soul of energy within him**. Father was desperate.

Comment: Sorry, but that answer does not satisfies myself. You are saying that Father approaches Edward not because he is a philosopher’s stone but because he has energy in his soul after saying all humans are kinda "philosopher’s stone with one soul as a power source" so Father could easily search for anyone alse including all the humans there present who are more inoffensive that Edward.

Comment: @Fallen Yes. Not only was Edward pinned down and had only one arm, but he was physically the closest to Father (who was struggling to even walk), with Al, Mei, and the others at much greater distances. Not only that, but Ed was the one toward whom Father had the most anger. Who better to go after than a one-armed, pinned, nearby object of rage?